# Why haven't I earned the Electorate badge yet?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

I have ~700 votes, and am sure that a lot more than 25% are on questions.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The badge description speaketh thus, "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

Comment: @hims056: Why VTC as dup with something that is itself closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Caleb - Because it gives detailed information of what this OP wants. And this is not discouraged here.

Comment: @Stano, there is no minimum limit on total votes except that, it should not cross 2400, when question votes are 600.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man Thanks for correcting me, so that 2400 is the maximum amount of votes on answers, if you want to receive the badge already with the minimum required 600 votes on questions. Simply said: "Voted on at least 600 questions and the vote ratio Q:A is above 25% == 1:4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vote on 600 questions not total votes. At present you have voted on 549 questions.  So vote on more 51 questions.

Comment: I have 700. 25% of 700 is 175. I have way more then 175 votes on questions.

Comment: i thought 25% :S

Comment: @user1721135 - Rule of Electorate badge is to vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes.

Comment: ahh now i get it.

Answer (score 6):

Information available at [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721135/user1721135). You need 51 more votes on question.

> [image]

**Electorate badge** Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.
**AND** here is showing both condition should necessarily be true.

Comment: Note that this is part of the "activity" summary page, and *isn't available on any of the tabs in the "votes" details page.  It took me many minutes of searching to find this after getting curious about my voting record, long after getting the badge.

Answer (score 3):

You have voted on 549 question, still you need to vote on 51 question to earn that badge. As per the Electorate Badge you atleast require 600 votes on question, which is not a total votes count.

see the badge criteria,

#### Electorate

- gold; awarded once
- Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions

  - Comment votes do not count

This seems to be an especially confusing badge, so here are some examples to address cases commonly complained about on MSO. `Total` is just the total number of votes cast (`Questions` + `Answers`) and `Ratio` is the total number of votes cast that are on questions.

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
│ Questions │ Answers │ Total │ Ratio │ Electorate awarded? │  
├───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
│       600 │    2400 │  3000 │   20% │   No; ratio too low │  
│       201 │     401 │   602 │  ~33% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       599 │       0 │   599 │  100% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       600 │       0 │   600 │  100% │                 Yes │  
│       500 │     500 │  1000 │   50% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       650 │     650 │  1300 │   50% │                 Yes │  
└───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

[Original Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/227860)

Comment: In the future, rather than copying and pasting an answer from another Meta question, please flag the question as a duplicate.